# error with dynamic compile golang

Tags: go, compiler-errors, dynamic-compilation

i'm trying to dynamically compile go file for windows in linux host my code:

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, 世界")
}
```

when i'm trying to compile:

```
root@vm:/home/ubuntu/workspace# echo $GOROOT
/opt/go
root@vm:/home/ubuntu/workspace# echo $GOPATH
/home/ubuntu/workspace/
root@vm:/home/ubuntu/workspace# go build // works !
root@vm:/home/ubuntu/workspace# go build -compiler gccgo // works !
root@vm:/home/ubuntu/workspace# ls -sh workspace 
28K workspace
root@vm:/home/ubuntu/workspace# GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 go build // works !
root@vm:/home/ubuntu/workspace# GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 go build -compiler gccgo
# _/home/ubuntu/workspace
./main.go:2:11: error: import file ‘fmt’ not found
 import "fmt"
           ^
./main.go:4:2: error: reference to undefined name ‘fmt’
  fmt.Println("Hello, 世界")
  ^
root@vm:/home/ubuntu/workspace#
```

also in windows there is error:

```
C:\Users\vm\Documents\aatest>go build -compiler gccgo
go build _/C_/Users/vm/Documents/aatest: : exec: "C:\\Users\\vm\\Documents\\aatest": file does not exist

C:\Users\vm\Documents\aatest>go build main.go -compiler gccgo
named files must be .go files
```

help with any platform will be fine

Comment: Is https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GccgoCrossCompilation#build-1 relevant here? And what versiob of gcc do you have (as in http://grokbase.com/t/gg/golang-nuts/159cbsm8mg/go-nuts-building-goarch-386-c-shared-library-using-gccgo)

Comment: I have realized the gccgo isn't supported on Windows yet, so I have tried xgo not working, my gcc version is 4.8.4

Comment: That version seems way too old to support the latest go version needed for cross-compilation.

Comment: So what's the problem, if it compiles fine (without the use of -compiler) the binary should still run just fine from your first build without the compiler flag you should be able to just run that file on Windows?

Comment: @Datsik I can compile to windows successfully, but I can't dynamically compile to windows

Comment: @VonC what is the version I need to compile to windows ?

Comment: @MostafaDahab ok. You should fix your question title and body then because it's misleading.

Comment: @MostafaDahab the most recent version you can find. 5+.

Comment: @Datsik if you read the title "error with dynamic compile golang" npt "error with compile golang" there is "Dynamic"

Comment: @VonC I have tried with the latest gcc5 same issue